# React Typescript - InferProps accepts null but JSX Attributes does not (i.e. id)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I am starting a new Typescript and React project, I have experience in both of this languages but joining them together has proven rather difficult.

The problem I'm facing now is that when I want to receive an id to use as a prop and define with PropTypes, when I use InferProps to get the types for my component it shows the id type as "string | null | undefined" and the div component only accepts "string | null".

```
import PropTypes, { InferProps } from 'prop-types';

export function TestComponent({ id }: InferProps<typeof TestComponent.propTypes>) {
  return <div id={id}></div>;
}

TestComponent.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string
};
```

[image]

[image]

I thinked about changing the type directly in PropTypes.string but there must be a better solution.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should have prop types as

```
TestComponent.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired | undefined
};
```

`isRequired` makes prop to be non-null and non-undefined.

So that Id won't be null.

Note: Not tested.

Comment: I don't want it required, I don't mind that it is undefined, since there are times where this component won't need an ID, I just want it to not be null, so it's type, when not required, is "string | undefined", this way it matched the type for JSX attribute id

Comment: In PropTypes, we can specify non-null and non undefined by making it isRequired but not possible to specify as non-null alone.

`id: PropTypes.string.isRequired | undifined` Try this so that is string and undefined but not null

Comment: This code example does not compile, it's not valid TS syntax.